# How to write interface for the response for angular's must httpclient

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to fetch the data from api using the angular's new httpclient, I get the error property doesnt exist on type IMessage[]. How do i write an interface for the following response,

```
{"data":{"Messages":[{"Id":28,"MessageContent":"test data tsn","FromUserId":"74df8f98-2925-4242-8d32-8b09f3691396","UserName":"365@test.com","ToUserId":"96b1c943-ade0-4026-b8ed-0f4a6231e586","ProductId":null,"ParentMessageId":null,"Subject":"Test Message by Dev Team","StyleNumber":null}],"Pagination":{"Page":1,"PageLength":20,"TotalRecords":20,"TotalPages":1},"MessageLimit":{"TotalMessageCount":5,"RemainingMessageCount":3}}}
```

What i tried here,

```
export interface IMessage {
    data: {
        Messages: Messages[];
    };
}

interface Messages {
    id: number;
    messageContent: string;
    fromUserId: string;
    toUserId: string;
    productId?: number;
    parentMessageId?: number;
    subject: string;
    styleNumber?: string;
}
```

My [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gguq86?file=app/hello.component.ts) on stackblitz

[image]

```
// Here is the code
    import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { IMessage } from './message.interface';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit  {
  constructor (private http: HttpClient) {
        console.log('Message repository service instance');
    }
        readonly ROOT_URL = '//52.70.78.117:7111/api/message';
ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllMessages();
  }
  @Input() name: string;
  messages;
  getAllMessages(): Observable<IMessage[]> {
    this.getAllMessagesFromApi()
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log('data is =>', data.data);
      this.messages = data;
    },
    err => {
      console.log('Error occured while fetching message List');
    });
    return;
  }
  getAllMessagesFromApi(): Observable<IMessage[]> {
      return this.http.get<IMessage[]>(`${this.ROOT_URL}/list`);
  }
}
```

Comment: seems like your are correct. you may add Pagination and MessageLimit properties.

Comment: But that shows a type error

Comment: If you're asking about an error, post the relevant code, and the exact and complete error message.

Comment: check the case, typescript as javascripts is case sensitive, for example in your response you have `FromUserId` but in your interface you have `fromUserId`

Comment: Hi all, screenshot and code on stackblitz added.

Comment: You still haven't posted the error. But you've told TypeScript that getAllMessages() returns an Observable<IMessage[]>, but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Karty you are trying to access the `data` property (`data.data`) of an array, which you can't do. According to your interface your api should be returning the type `IMessage` not `IMessage[]`

Comment: @JB Nizet The error is the screenshot(of editor) that is posted on the question. Error: " property data doesnt exist on type IMessage[].

Comment: Hi @LLai. I need to access the array of messages. How do i do that?

Comment: @Karty If you change your method to return `Observable<IMessage>` & your http request to return `this.http.get<IMessage>` you can access the array of messages with `data.data.Messages`. Check out this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vzsx4e?file=app/hello.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks. Would you like to write  this as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should change what type your `getAllMessagesFromAPI()` method returns to `IMessage`

```
// method returns type IMessage
getAllMessagesFromApi(): Observable<IMessage> { 
    // http request returns type IMessage
    return this.http.get<IMessage>(`${this.ROOT_URL}/list`); 
}
```

Now you can access your array of messages

```
.subscribe(data => {
    this.messages = data.data.Messages;
},
```